# numerical solution of an equation containing an integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have the following problem:
given r, I have to find the {x,y} which satisfies:

```
Integrate[1/(E^((2*x^2-4*x*d+2*d^2+2*y^2)/(8*d+4*r^2))*(Sqrt[d]*(2*d+r^2))),{d,0,Infinity}]==1
```

However, of all the solutions, I am interested to find the one which has the maximum y.
Unfortunately, the integral can be solved only numerically.
Any help?
Bye

---

Many tahnks. It works now. However the calcualtion looks quite unstable.
Have a look to my .nb:

this is the mathematica .nb file:

```
 rangeρ = {0, 0.1, 1, 10, 100};
rangeRy = {10^-5, 10^-4, 10^-3, 10^-2, 10^-1, 10^0, 10^1, 10^2, 10^3, 
   10^4, 10^5};
integrale[ξ_, ψ_, ζ_, ρ_] := 
  NIntegrate[ (
   E^(-((2 ξ^2 - 4 ξ δ + 2 δ^2 + 2 ψ^2 + 
      2 ζ^2 + (ρ^2 ζ^2)/δ)/(
    8 δ + 4 ρ^2))))/(
   Sqrt[δ] (2 δ + ρ^2)), {δ, 0, Infinity}];
solu = Table[
  NMaximize[ψ, 
    2/Sqrt[π] Ry integrale[ξ, ψ, 0, ρ] == 
     1, {ξ, ψ}][[2, 2, 2]], {ρ, rangeρ}, {Ry, 
   rangeRy}]
```

---

[image: for example, the large numebr obtained for rho = 0, do not have much sense]

### for example, the large numebr obtained fro rho = 0, do not have much sense

I beg your pardon but I cannot manage to paste a notebbok as you did before.
My code is:

```
ranger = {0, 0.1, 1, 10, 100};
rangeRy = {10^-5, 10^-4, 10^-3, 10^-2, 10^-1, 10^0, 10^1, 10^2, 10^3, 10^4, 10^5};

integrale[x_,y_,z_,r_]:=NIntegrate[(E^(-((2 x^2-4 x d+2 d^2+2 y^2+2 z^2+(r^2 z^2)/d)/(8 d+4 r^2))))/(Sqrt[d] (2 d+r^2)), {d,0,Infinity}];
solu=Table[NMaximize[y,2/Sqrt[π] Ry integrale[ξ,ψ,0,r]==1,{ξ,ψ}][[2,2,2]],{r,ranger},{Ry,rangeRy}]
```

If you willl run it you will see very big numbers that are surely a mistake. Problably there is the need of increasing the accuracy or the working precision?
many thanks

Comment: Please edit to add links to-from the cross-post on Wolfram Community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First define the integral

```
int[x_, y_, r_] :=NIntegrate[1/(E^((2*x^2 - 4*x*d + 2*d^2 + 2*y^2)/(8*d + 4*r^2))*(Sqrt[d]*(2*d + r^2))), {d, 0, Infinity}]
```

Now you can maximize as intended. For example `r=1`

```
NMaximize[{y , int[x, y, 1] == 1}, {x, y}]
(* {1.30787, {x -> 0.404927, y -> 1.30787}}*)
```